# How to force my app to fetch the localhost IP of my laptop (which hosts the wamp server) every time my laptop connect to different network?

Tags: android

I am developing an application which basically connects to my laptop which hosts the server ... what I need is to test the app on my android device and I know I have to type the localhost IP of my laptop to establish the connection but my problem when I ,my laptop and my mobile move to another network, the network assigns another localhost IP to my laptop which in turn requires me to replace the old one with it every time I make that move ... so is there anyway to avoid this ?

Comment: hardcode it with 127.0.0.1 during development..

Comment: isn't it sufficient to address your PC by its hostname ? The hostname should stay the same, no matter which network you connect to.